# GAE Namespace based on subdomain

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces, multi-tenant

I am considering a multi-tenant environment where I can have each tenant access a different subdomain and then potentially allocate a namespace based on that domain.

For instance,

```
tenantA.mydomain.com
tenantB.mydomain.com
```

Then I would want to have namespace `tenantA` for all tenantA data and `tenantB` for all tenantB data.

From the docs, it sounds like I would accomplish this in my `appengine_config.py` file and do something like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import namespace_manager

def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():

    this_namespace = get_namespace_from_subdomain()
    return this_namespace
```

First question, is this a reasonable/good approach?

Second question, it's unclear what variables are available in this scope - any pointers on how to implement the get_namepsace_from_subdomain() function?

Finally, if there were some functionality I wanted to provide that would cross namespaces could this still be achieved with a global namespace? For instance, say a user has an account in multiple tenants and I want to give a view of his activity across all tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best approach to take. The problem with this approach is that you're tightly coupling you application with the infrastructure in a way. Domain and subdomain are just an easier way to access a machine bound to a specific ip address. I would classify domain names to be part of the infrastructure, not really part of the application. If you go with the above mentioned approach you're introducing some knowledge about the infrastructure into the application and thus making your application less flexible. What happens if you, for some reason, sometime in the future decide that your client A should use clientA.mydomain.com? or how about keyClientA.myotherdomain.com? Or how about you want to allow your client A to use their domain name, i.e. support.clientA.com? If your application does not know anything about domains and infrastructure setup then it's a lot easier to just reconfigure DNS server and get the portability.

If I had this scenario, I would have some kind of mapping of URLs to a tenant id, and then use that tenant id as a namespace name. This way you can easily map different URLs to a tenant id. You can even map multiple URLs to the same tenant id and expose the same application on multiple URLs. Your mapping can be stored in a simple config file or even in the AppEngine datastore itself within global namespace. If the config is stored in the AppEngine datastore, you can have your admin section of the application (or even another AppEngine module) which you can use to update config in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the enhanced answer - turns out that the code mentioned in the answer above touches on this approach as well. It advises "If the mapping is stored in datastore, we would probably not wish to look it up on every query" which I imagine could introduce significant overhead. Would you then store the entire mapping in memcache in global namespace? Or rely on ndb caching?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely use memcache to improve performance. Although make sure you have a persistent copy in the datastore in case memcache is cleared.

Comment: Having given some more thought about performance, you should achieve best performance ( fastest lookup time) if you have lookup table hard coded in your application in form of some hash table or similar data structure

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and reasonable to use multi-tenancy in your app based on sub-domains, though from my experience you should also allow overriding the namespace by using a url param.

e.g.

```
tenantB.mydomain.com/?tenant=tenantA => namespace=tenantA
```

This will make you life a lot easier and will enable you to test your newest appengine versions on *.appspot.com before moving them to production (especially if you are planning on SSL access).

Once you set the namespace than only the entities under that namespace will be available, you can change the namespace via code whenever you want - the scope doesn't matter.
for the sub-domain - you can parse it out from the one of the client's request headers.

you can write whatever you want to the global namespace and access it whenever you want via code. for the scenario you described, you need to save the user activity on the global namespace.

also, take a loot at the official python example for using namespaces from the GAE team.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-namespaces-python
It gives you everything you need to get started.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a useful article that cleared things up. "datastore or memcache attempt to resolve the namespace" - doesn't this mean every read and write to datastore or memcache involves running `def namespace_manager_default_namespace_for_request():`? Sounds like potential for a lot of overhead, no? And to clarify my question about "scope", I was confused how to get environment information like subdomain into `appengine_config.py` but it looks like the os module is the answer there

Comment: @diddleboo, it really depends on the use-case, in most of the cases I encountered it is enough to set the namespace per user request/session. We have a couple of large production apps running and this was never a performance issue. I'm guessing that in python there is an object for http request you can extract the sub-domain from.